# How can I declare a variable in model.sdf file?

Tags: sdformat

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi everyone,

I hope this is not a silly question. Is there a way to declare a variable in model.sdf file of a robot and use it multiple times? I've made a hexapod and it has some fixed values such as link length or width. If I want to change one leg's values I have to do the same for all the others. I believe this is done by xacro files in ROS but what if I want to do this without ROS?

Thanks in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/14063/how-can-i-declare-a-variable-in-model.sdf-file?/) by [elmuhn](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2751/elmuhn/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 3 on 2016-08-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

You could use [embedded ruby](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ERuby) to generate parametrized models.

- [Here](http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/8753/algorithmic-world-generation/)'s an example of an SDF model with embedded ruby.
- [Here](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/src/39e64e7a40f12702cd2ed1cb80d219e3a7ecd4b2/worlds/torsional_friction_demo.world.erb?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default)'s an example of an SDF world with embedded ruby.

To regenerate the SDF from the erb template in the command line:

```
erb model.rsdf > model.sdf
```

Obs: see [this](http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/8753/algorithmic-world-generation/) answer.

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2016-08-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [elmuhn](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2751/elmuhn/) on 2016-08-08**:
Thank you so much chapulina! This works very well. I was also thinking of something that I can implement a method in the sdf's API in order to declare a variable or anything I wish. For instance, when I look at the joint.sdf file in the sdformat directory, I can see the joint element's attributes or its elements. I tried to make my own element like declaration.sdf and gave a name and a value as attributes. However it didn't work at all. Would there be another way to do so?